# Why don't I have Apex classes & triggers in Eclipse?

Tags: apex, ide, eclipse

So I need to deactivate an apex trigger and class that my org no longer uses.

I've read up a little on how to do this from Eclipse and gone down that route. I've successfully gotten into Eclipse (JDK 8 for Mac Cocoa and Eclipse Kepler 4.3), I've linked Force.com IDE version 31.0, and I'm following the steps from this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005417&language=en_US) with the help of this handy-dandy shows-you-every-step [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/asagarwal/how-to-delete-deactivate-apex-class-trigger-from-salesforce-production-org). I create a new Force.com project, log into production, and then I hit this hurdle:

No apex classes or triggers appear among my options for metadata components. I receive an error message that says "Package Manifest Content Warning" Exception happened when resolving component type(s), so no component will be added to package manifest editor for these types.
* ExternalDataSource
See log for detail exception messages.

Disclaimer: I do not have a developer background, and Eclipse and the idea of operating out the IDE is daunting to me, I just need to deactivate this trigger. I'm relatively comfortable with Developer Console, but I only really use it for SOQL queries, editing apex triggers, and testing apex code, and everything I know about those I've taught myself over the past six months. Laymans terms are MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Do you just have to de-activate it, or do you want it completely removed? If you just need to de-activate it, in an effort to avoid Eclipse completely, you can un-check the "Active" box for the trigger in the sandbox and deploy it to production.

Comment: Is the trigger part of a managed package? When viewing the Trigger in setup, does it have a little downward pointing arrow into a box next to the name of the trigger?

Comment: Hi @kbentsen. I only need to de-activate it, so if there's a work around that doesn't involve Eclipse, I'd be welcome to it. However if I deactivate the trigger the code coverage goes to 0%, so I can't deploy it. As you can likely predict, the test class also fails, so I can't regain code coverage.

(I was under the impression from the knowledge article that the only way to deactivate is via Eclipse.)

Comment: @greenstork good thought, but nope -- it's a custom built trigger.

Comment: Just deactivate it, deploy, and write a unit test for it to provide coverage, if you're comfortable doing that. It will likely be faster than resolving any issues with Eclipse/IDE

Comment: @Bri I've written Unit tests to provide coverage before, but never for inactive triggers. Does that even work? I don't understand how it could cover the code if the code isn't active.

Comment: why not comment out the trigger and associated handler classes, if any plus test class, then use changeset to deploy? If you have other active classes/triggers/testmethods, your code coverage should in aggregate still be fine

Comment: Alright, the issue seems to be resolved. There were two issues:

1. the problem I was having about not finding the apex classes or triggers in apex was because I was logged into production, not the sandbox. The SF knowledge article said to log into sandbox, but I missed that bc the powerpoint said production.

2. from Eclipse I then deleted the class, marked the trigger as inactive, then deployed the trigger from sandbox, NOT Eclipse. Why I had to use Eclipse but couldn't deploy from it, I don't know, so I'll tinker more next time, but at least this is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops -- commented my answer rather than answering question here: #newbiemistake

There were two issues:

1. the problem I was having about not finding the apex classes or triggers in apex was because I was logged into production, not the sandbox. The SF knowledge article said to log into sandbox, but I missed that bc the powerpoint said production.
2. from Eclipse I then deleted the class, marked the trigger as inactive, then deployed the trigger from sandbox, NOT Eclipse. Why I had to use Eclipse but couldn't deploy from it, I don't know, so I'll tinker more next time, but at least this is resolved.